# Left align bulleted lists and numbered list

Tags: css

On this page http://www.malaysiajobsdb.com/how-to-write-a-resume/
you can see the ordered list and the unordered list is not aligned properly.

Ideally, the bullets (or the numbers) should be left aligned. For example, the number "1." should be left aligned (to the left) and on the same line as the heading "Personal Information".

Any idea how I can do this? Preferably, I want to include the CSS inline, at the <ul> or <li> itself, so that I do not disturb the appearance (and alignment) of other parts of the site.

I am using Firefox. The above problem is clearly visible in Firefox, but not so in Chrome.

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this inline css to your `<ul>` or `<ol>`

```
<ol style="list-style-type: none;">
```

**Update:**

To keep the line numbers remove the above code and replace it with

```
<ol style="list-style: decimal outside;">
```

**Another Update :)**

For `<ul>`:

```
<ul style="list-style: circle outside;">
```

Comment: Just tried that quickly. It doesn't work well, because it removes the numbering. I still want the numbering, only that it has to be left aligned and should stay on the same line as the heading.

Comment: <ol style="list-style: decimal outside;"> works great! But, how do I do that for the <ul>?

Comment: Updated my answer. That should do it :)